# Limit pg_search to the associations of an individual User object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg-search

For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end

#  name       :string(255)
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

How would you use pg_search to do a full text search of the names of cars that only a single User instance has (versus all cars)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of pg_search. It sounds like what you want to do is chain a pg_search_scope onto an association:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch
  belongs_to :user
  pg_search_scope :search_by_name, against: :name
end

user = User.find(1)
user.cars.search_by_name("Ford")
```

Comment: Can this work also with multisearch?

I was looking at 

`odyssey = EpicPoem.create!(:title => "Odyssey", :author => "Homer")
rose = Flower.create!(:color => "Red")
PgSearch.multisearch("Homer")`

and if

`user = User.first`

it doesn't appear there's any way to scope `PgSearch` on `user.`

Comment: No, you would need to set up a separate `pg_search_scope` on User to do that.